# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap-env:Client.InvalidAction] Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist

Tags: php, soap, sabre

I am try to connect Sabre API using PHP SOAP Class.

Test3.php

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/usg/SessionCreateRQ.wsdl',
varray( 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE ) );

$params = array(
'Username'=>'test@tester.com',
'Password'=>'passwrod'
'Organization'=>'Test',
'Domain'=> 'domain name'
);

$auth = array(
    'UserName'=>'test@tester.com',
    'Password'=>'password',
    'SystemId'=> array('_'=>'DATA','Param'=>'PARAM'),
    );

$header = new SoapHeader('https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc','Auth', $auth,false);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$returnwwww = $client->__soapCall('SessionCreateRQ',$params);
print_r($returnwwww);
```

I am geeting this error. "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap-env:Client.InvalidAction] Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist."

Comment: try $client->SessionCreateRQ($params);

Comment: I tried with - try $client->SessionCreateRQ($params);
I got this error - Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'POS' property in

Comment: $client->SessionCreateRQ($params); is giving error so your $params are not correct probably. you will have to check $params. use $client->__getTypes(); and $client->__getFunctions() to your aid.

Comment: Again i tried with 'POS' params - Now i got this error (Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap-env:Client.InvalidAction] Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist.)

Comment: you definitely have error in your $params. $client->__getTypes(); will surely help you to make $params. POS is an object in which you have another object Source in which you have string PseudoCityCode;

Comment: @rahulRaj - I have used  $client->__getTypes(). its returing some object with properties. How do i find parameters on that.

Comment: i recommend you to use SoapUI. this will give you better understanding.

Comment: is it GUI? for WSDL file extractor?

Comment: yes, search SoapUI in google. You will get it

Answer (score 0):

For how to on PHP, you can use the sample code in the DevStudio.

https://developer.sabre.com/resources/sample_code